How to use loop in this problem in python?
I have this formula for the profit, (profit = (unit * rent) - (unit * maintenance)), and I have gave the user input for the number of unit, rent, increase_rent and maintenance cost. So if the user types 50 for unit, 600 for rent/m, increase rent 30$/m, and maintenance cost $37, I want to print #of unit from 50 to 1 rent for each #of unit and profit if I have this number of units. So the loop should run for 50 times and each time it decreases the unit # so should be 1--(subtracting 1) and tell me the rent which is 30 (increase rent) so add that to the rent and the profit. How do I write the for loop for this?
for unit in range(50, 0, -1):
    profit = (unit * rent) - (unit * maintenance)
    rent1 = rent+increase_Rent
    print('Units     + Rent +     Profit')
    print( unit,  rent1,  profit)


As an aside, you can simplify (unit * rent) - (unit * maintenance) to just unit * (rent - maintenance).

It seems you already knew how to use a for loop, what is the problem with what you have?

Why does unit==10 have 10 times the cost and rent of unit==1? I'm not sure you have your data structured correctly.

To loop through the units, decrease them by 1, update rent and calculate profit each time. follow >
for u in range(50, 0, -1)
    rent += 30
    profit = (u * rent) - (u * 37)
    print(f"Units: {u}, Rent: {rent}, Profit: {profit}")


